# insertar un apostrofe antes de una consulta para excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Tengo este resultado de una consulta

```
$consulta .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
```

donde la variable `' . $v . '` es un numero que contiene ceros a la izquierda, para que excel reconozca ese numero en formato texto, debo de agregar un apostrofe ' antes del numero el problema es que php separa las variables con apostrofes, como inserto el apostrofe antes de la variable algo asi pero genera error por que no se cierra el apostrofe en php: `' ' . $v . '`

el resultado de la consulta debe quedar asi: '000018

```html
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
    $data[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $data[$i]['codigo_op'] = $row['codigo_op'];
    $data[$i]['entrega01_clave'] = $row['entrega01_clave'];
    $data[$i]['descripcion_articulo'] = $row['descripcion_articulo'];
    $i++;
}
```

unicamente el campo **codigo_op** debe tener el apostrofe antes del numero

Comment: Creo que puedes hacer algo asi: `$consulta .= "<td>'" . $v . "</td>";`, pero no estoy 100% seguro, por eso no lo publico como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun tu codigo, podrias usar:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){ 
    $data[$i]['id'] = $i; 
    $data[$i]['codigo_op'] = "'".$row['codigo_op']; 
    $i++; 
}
```

Considera que si utilizas `$data[$i]['codigo_op']`para otras operaciones podrias tener errores, entonces usa dos variables, una para pintar al excel y otra para operaciones:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){ 
    $data[$i]['id'] = $i; 
    //para operaciones
    $data[$i]['codigo_op'] = $row['codigo_op']; 
    //para excel
    $data[$i]['codigo_op_excel'] = "'".$row['codigo_op']; 
    $i++; 
}
```

Comment: perfecto gracias ya funciona

Answer (score 2):

Tienes algunas opciones:

```
//segun tu codigo, usar backslah (\) antes del apostrofe
$consulta .= '<td>\'' . $v . '</td>';
```

o bien:

```
//usar comillas ("") para encerrar el codigo html 
$consulta .= "<td>'" . $v . "</td>";
```

o bien:

```
//usar comillas ("") y no usar concatenadores, php detecta que $v es una variable y reemplaza su valor 
$consulta .= "<td>'$v</td>";
```

Comment: vale si funciona el unico detalle que no me percate es que le agrega a todas las columnas el apostrofe y solo es en uno que es numerica, la funcion es : $data[$i]['codigo_op'] = $row['codigo_op']; donde puedo indicar el apostrofe antes de esto.

Comment: Al valor `$data[$i]['codigo_op']` agregale apostrofe donde lo uses, ejem `"<td>'".$data[$i]['codigo_op']."</td>"`

Comment: o almacenalo en una variable con el apostrofe: `$valor = "'".$data[$i]['codigo_op']`

Comment: por favor publica el código para entenderlo mejor

Comment: listo disculpa solo lo necesito para que agrege el apostrofe solo en el campo variable del while codigo_op los demas no deben tener el apostrofe